# Mot pour dire « rendre chinois »

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Je pense à toutes ces marques que la Chine reprend pour imiter l'Occident, *Wii* qui devient *Vii*, *Adidas* qui devient *Adadas*, etc.

Existe-il un mot pour dire « rendre chinois »? *Chiniser*? *Chinoisifier*? *Sinoiser*? (Exemples peu sérieux. Quoi que le dernier…)

Comment: À mon sens, ce n'est pas que de la contrefaçon, il y a également la notion d'adaptation et d'assimilation à la culture Chinoise.

Comment: Je ne sais pas. Il existe le mot "chinoiser". Toutefois, on l'utilise dans un différent contexte selon mon dictionnaire de mots de la même famille "chinoiser = Chicaner sur une chose insignifiante, mesquine.".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Serait-ce *sinisation* que vous cherchez ?

- [la définition du Wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sinisation) :

  > Processus par lequel le mode de vie, la langue etc. deviennent plus chinois. […]
- [la définition du TLF](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/sinisation) :

  > Rendre chinois; donner certains caractères chinois. […]

Comment: Merci Stéphane pour l'édition !

Comment: À noter que le verbe existe aussi : [siniser](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/siniser).